# How to disable EOP for the whole organization in our exchange hybrid environment?

Tags: email, spam, exchange-hybrid

set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -enabled $false only disable the EOP for mailboxes. it cannot ensure new mailbox's EOP is also disable. So what is the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EOP has many features, such as anti-spam protection, spam management, anti-malware protection and mail routing and connectors and so on. And some feature, such as “Inbound anti-spam protection”, it is always enabled and can't be disabled. Why do you want to disable it or which feature do you want to disable?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/eop/eop-features

For your command, you could run the following one for all existing mailboxes:
Get-Mailbox | Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration –Enabled $False

Yes, this cannot ensure new mailbox's EOP is also disable. You need run it periodically.